# How to pass the results of a function from one file to another file

Tags: python, function, input, attributes, arguments

I get error when I print the result of a function in the main file (named as INPUT.py). The functions are made in another file (named as ENGINE.py). The  error is: AttributeError: module 'ENGINE' has no attribute 'cross_section'
I cannot understand why do I get such error.

Here the code example:

#-- Main file: INPUT.py

```
class Duct:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width 
        self.height = height 
    
Duct_ret = Duct(0.1, 0.1)

Duct_ret.width= 0.4
Duct_ret.height= 0.3

import ENGINE as EN
print(EN.cross_section)
```

#-- Engine file: ENGINE.py

```
from INPUT import width, height

def cross_section(self,):
    c_s=height*width
    return c_s
```

## Error:   AttributeError: module 'ENGINE' has no attribute 'cross_section'

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with this. `cross_section` is malformed as it has a spurious comma and also, is not in a class so should not reference self. Also the import of width and height from INPUT.py is meaningless and circular. You should pass those as arguments to the cross_section function. Also, you don't call cross section properly, you merely print the function itself, not the result of the called function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have a circular dependency in your code.

In `ENGINE.py`, you import `height` and `width` and in `INPUT.py` you import `ENGINE`.

You should pass `Duct_ret.height` and `Duct_ret.width` to your helper function instead of importing it.

So instead of this:

```
import ENGINE as EN
print(EN.cross_section)
```

do this:

```
import ENGINE as EN
print(EN.cross_section(Duct_ret.height, Duct_ret.width))
```

and in `ENGINE.py`, define the function like this:

```
def cross_section(height, width):
    c_s = height * width
    return c_s
```

NOTE: you also have `self` as an argument to `cross_section` which isn't right since `cross_section` is not a class method -- you just need to pass the relevant arguments to the function (which your original code didn't).

Side note: you should move your `import` to the start of the file in `INPUT.py` for better style in this case.

Comment: It says that height is not defined

Comment: Ah yes, in this case, in `INPUT.py`, you don't have `height` and `width` -- should be `Duct_ret.height` and `Duct_ret.width` instead. Updated the example. Though for style, you should rename the variable to `duct_ret` -- i.e. all lowercase instead of starting with a capital letter.

Comment: I still have the same problem:

Comment: print(EN.cross_section(duct_ret.height, duct_ret.width))

AttributeError: module 'ENGINE' has no attribute 'cross_section'

Comment: I made the file Engine as follow:from INPUT import duct_ret

def cross_section(width, height):
    c_s = height * width
    return c_s

Comment: Why are you `import`ing `duct_ret` in `ENGINE.py`? It does not require any `import`s -- if you follow my above explanation, we are *passing* all the relevant arguments to `cross_section()`. You should remove the `import`s from `ENGINE.py` --- having the `import`s in `ENGINE.py` is what caused your circular dependency in the first place, as I described above.

Comment: Thanks, it works well. sorry it was a distraction, here it s a bit late

Answer (score 0):

@costaparas has given a very detailed answer.

I also played around with the given code to find a solution. While trying to figure this out, I found there are 2 issues with your code:

1. You shouldn't be using **import** to get class variables in a different file.
2. You are using top level imports in both files with circular dependency which is causing the error.

Solution:

INPUT1.py

```
class Duct:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width 
        self.height = height 
    
Duct_ret = Duct(0.1, 0.1)

Duct_ret.width= 0.4
Duct_ret.height= 0.3

from ENGINE import cross_section1 as cs
cs(Duct_ret.width, Duct_ret.height)
```

ENGINE.py

```
def cross_section1(width,height):
    c_s=height*width
    print (c_s)
```